# awk to parse text file issue

Tags: unix, awk

I have just started to learn how to use awk to parse and print text file .

I have started with bellow code who can help me ?

NB: quote are mandatory at output file ( see desired output )

```
 awk '/^IPDATA=/ && /A|B|C| '{print "ADD IP ="$0"\n(\n  \Ref "$1",Type vlan="$2"\"\n)\n"}' file > file1
```

NB: Ref is the sum of line of IPREF here in the example we have three : [2]  && [2]  && [1].

the sample text file in fact is huge but I have summurized it :

```
IPDATA=A                IPID A            
IPDATA=A                IPREF   [2] =     
--- IPREF = VRID=A_1                      
--- IPREF = VRID=A_2                      
                                          
IPDATA=B                IPID B            
IPDATA=B                IPREF   [2] =     
--- IPREF = VRID=B_1                      
--- IPREF = VRID=B_2                      
                                          
IPDATA=C               IPID C             
IPDATA=C               IPREF    [1] =     
--- IPREF = VRID=C_1
```

I want to get bellow result :

```
"ADD IP=A "
( Ref  2
"Type vlan=VRID=A_1" 
"Type vlan=VRID=A_2" 
)
"ADD IP=B "          
( Ref  2              
"Type vlan=VRID=B_1" 
"Type vlan=VRID=B_2" 
)
"ADD IP=C "          
( Ref  1              
"Type vlan=VRID=C_1" 
)
```

thanks

Comment: Please don't edit old answered questions. Rather open new ones with complete details and your efforts thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v s1="\"" '
/^IPDATA/ && /IPID .*/{
  if(FNR>1){  print ")"  }
  print s1 "ADD IP" s1 "="s1 $NF OFS s1
  next
}
/^IPDATA.*IPREF.*\[[0-9]+\]/{
  match($0,/\[[^]]*/)
  print "( Ref sum of IPREF " substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
  next
}
/^--- IPREF/{
  print s1 "Type vlan="$NF s1
}
END{
  print ")"
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v s1="\"" '                                               ##Starting awk program from here.
/^IPDATA/ && /IPID .*/{                                        ##Checking condition if line starts IPDATA and having IPID here.
  if(FNR>1){  print ")"  }                                     ##Checking condition if FNR>1 then printing ) here.
  print s1 "ADD IP" s1 "="s1 $NF OFS s1                        ##Printing s1 ADD IP s1 equal to s1 last field OFS and s1 here.
  next                                                         ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/^IPDATA.*IPREF.*\[[0-9]+\]/{                                  ##Checking condition if line starts from IPDATA and having IPREF till [ digits ].
  match($0,/\[[^]]*/)                                          ##Using match to match from [ till ] in line.
  print "( Ref sum of IPREF " substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)    ##printing string as per request and sub-string from RSTART+1 to till RLENGTH-1 here.
  next
}
/^--- IPREF/{                                                  ##Checking conditon if line starts from --- IPREF then do following.
  print s1 "Type vlan="$NF s1                                  ##Printing s1 string last field and s1 here.
}
END{                                                           ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  print ")"                                                    ##Printing ) here.
}
' Input_file                                                   ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: sorry for my late response the problem is not fixed when I run the script nothing is displayed the output file is empty

Comment: @azzoudino32, Run it on terminal without taking output into a file then what it shows?

Comment: @azzoudino32, this is not the command I given not sure why you are running this one

Comment: @azzoudino32, please open a new question as editing questions too late is not recommended on SO, kindly open a new question and let me know then.

Comment: @azzoudino32, please do not delete this thread, this has been answered as per question. Rather open a new thread/question and mention complete details there for sample of input and expected output and let me know then.

Comment: @azzoudino32, please undo all edits in this question and make it as it was before to avoid any confusions for future users cheers